# jspc-maven-plugin not executed?

Tags: java, maven

I'm adding the jspc plugin like this in my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
               <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                     </goals>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                  <inputwebxml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</inputwebxml>
                  <sources>
                     <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/jsp</directory>
                     <includes>
                        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                     </includes>
                  </sources>
               </configuration>
               <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                     <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                     <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
                  </dependency>
               </dependencies>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

But, when I run `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies install`, I don't see any classes are generated.  From here, http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-use-pre-compiled-jsps-in-webapp.html, I'm supposed to see a `target/jsp-source` directory, but I don't have it.

Any problem with my pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the plugin inside [`<pluginManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) and it is not declared inside a `<plugins>`. Quoting Maven documentation (emphasis mine):

> Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, **it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one**

which is not the case here.

As such, you just need to remove the `<pluginManagement>` element and let the plugin be declared directly inside `<plugins>`.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
            <!-- rest of configuration -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</buil>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I got it working now, but I have below exception thrown, and i don't  see any result in "target/jsp-source" which is now created.  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Missing tools.jar at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes/classes.jar. Expression: file.exists()
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:395)
"

Comment: @Bomin That's a completely different problem then! :) I suggest you create a new question with your complete POM and stacktrace.