# java.lang.AssertionError thrown when using "maven-compiler-plugin"

Tags: java, maven

This is a follow up question of my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292102/jspc-maven-plugin-not-executed).  Now, I have the plugin running, but I don't see any result in `target/jsp-source`.  Here's what's in pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
         <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <phase>compile</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
            <inputwebxml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</inputwebxml>
            <sources>
               <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/jsp</directory>
               <includes>
                  <include>**/*.jsp</include>
               </includes>
            </sources>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

After I run `clean dependency:copy-dependencies install`, I have below exception thrown `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Missing tools.jar at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes/classes.jar. Expression: file.exists()`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Missing tools.jar at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes/classes.jar. Expression: file.exists()
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:395)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:683)
   at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.CompilationMojoSupport.findToolsJar(CompilationMojoSupport.groovy:371)
   at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.CompilationMojoSupport.this$4$findToolsJar(CompilationMojoSupport.groovy)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:78)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrent0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:112)
   at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.CompilationMojoSupport.execute(CompilationMojoSupport.groovy:318)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Is this because my JRE level? 1.8?

Comment: Hmm... it might be worth trying version 3.3 of the maven-compiler-plugin to see if it was a bug in 3.1 that has since been fixed.

Comment: Try installing Oracle JDK. There might just be a difference in the name of the "JDK jar": `classes.jar` vs `tools.jar`

Comment: I am using Oracel JDK...

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: I guess I had, but it's just too long